# python requests equivalent to curl -H

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, sparkcore

I'm trying to subscribe to an event stream coming from my particle photon. 
The [docs](http://docs.particle.io/photon/firmware/#spark-publish) suggest

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN_GOES_HERE}" \
https://api.particle.io/v1/events/motion-detected
```

I've tried

```
address3 ='https://api.particle.io/v1/events/motion-detected'
data = {'access_token': access_token}
r3 = requests.get(address3,params=data)
```

but I get nothing, and I mean nothing, in response

I expect a response like:

```
event: motion-detected
data: {"data":"intact","ttl":"60","published_at":"2015-06-25T05:08:22.136Z","coreid":"coreid"}

event: motion-detected
data: {"data":"broken","ttl":"60","published_at":"2015-06-25T05:08:23.014Z","coreid":"coreid"}
```

I just don't understand what curl is doing relative to what requests is doing. 
Thanks for the help,
JR

Answer (score 2):

[Custom headers](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) are passed as a dictionary in `headers` argument

```
address3 ='https://api.particle.io/v1/events/motion-detected'
data = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN_GOES_HERE}'}
r3 = requests.get(address3, headers=data)
```

`params` argument is used to pass [URL parameters](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls). Basically your code issues a request to `https://api.particle.io/v1/events/motion-detected?access_token=token_goes_here`, this can be veriefied by printing url `print(r3.url)`

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Alik's response, custom headers are passed as a dictionary in the `headers` argument. In your case, that would be

```
address3 ='https://api.particle.io/v1/events/motion-detected'
data = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
r3 = requests.get(address3, headers=data)
```

Since this is authentication, the cleanest way would be to implement a custom authentication handler that set this header as described in the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#custom-authentication).