# Curl to requests; max retries exceeded

Tags: python, curl

I've seen this:
[python requests equivalent to curl -H](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041994/python-requests-equivalent-to-curl-h)

but when I try and make my own python request I get the "Max retries exceeded with url:" error.

I am trying to convert this command

```
curl.exe -H "x-api-key: aORMdWt3AX90YewgsRfYM7Y77eUQws8M75Mb8TIF" https://cqh77pglf1.execute­api.us­west­2.amazonaws.com/prod/data/location/­71.1043443253471,­42.3150676015829/time/2009­12­25
```

into

```
import requests
headers = {"x­-api-­key": "aORMdWt3AX90YewgsRfYM7Y77eUQws8M75Mb8TIF"}

r = requests.post('https://cqh77pglf1.execute­api.us­west­2.amazonaws.com/prod/data/location/­71.1043443253471,­42.3150676015829/time/2009­12­25', headers=headers)
```

(I've tried get as well)

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note when I try running the curl command I get a "This app can't run on Windows" aghhhhh Windows. Could that be why the python requests is not working as well?

Comment: What is the value of `r.status_code` and `r.content`?

Comment: Update your question with full traceback when running `requests`. About error of `curl`, it seems like your `curl` arch doesn't match your os arch.

Answer (score 0):

Try `requests.get` instead of `requests.post`, that curl command is probably calling GET and not POST.